# Javascript : repeat function not work

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function to fly DIV from top right to bottom left:

```
var myObj;

function infly() {
    myObj=document.getElementById('mydiv');
    myObj.style.right='0px';
    myObj.style.top='0px';
}

function flyer() {  
    var x=parseInt(myObj.style.right);
    var y=parseInt(myObj.style.top); 

    x+=1;
    y+=1;  

    myObj.style.right=x+'px';
    myObj.style.top=y+'px'; 

}

function repeat()
{
setTimeout(flyer,5000)
}
```

And HTML code is:

```
<body onLoad="infly()">

<div id="mydiv">
</div>

<a href="" onClick="javascript:repeat()">Fly</a>

...
..
.
```

But `repeat` function not work. When I remove this function in every click my DIV fly correctly.

I try with `setInterval('fly();', 10);` but no success.

Thanks for any helps.

---

Update:

I edit the code and correct `repeat` function but still not work.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
setTimeout(fly,5000)
```

instead of

```
setTimeout("fly()","5000()")
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of setTimeout should be a number:

```
setTimeout(fly,5000)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Updated, better not to use "fly()":

> code in the alternate syntax, is a string of code you want to execute
>   after delay milliseconds. (Using this syntax is not recommended for
>   the same reasons as using eval())

Comment: @WillemMulder That's another optimization. This answer offers an answer to the question, and includes a link to the relevant documentation. So +1.

Comment: Never, never, never pass a string to a setTimeout/setInterval or the context will need to be EVALuated. it's definitely a bad practice

Comment: @RobW I did not disagree with mamoo's answer per se, but meant to improve on it. eval is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that makes the div fly. I styled it so you could see it. Your code only called flyer once, and without setting the position to absolute the div will not redisplay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var K_CYCLES = 20;
  var numcycles = 0;

  function infly() {
    myObj = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    myObj.style.right = '0px';
    myObj.style.top = '0px';

  }

  function flyer() {  

    var x = parseInt(myObj.style.right);
    var y = parseInt(myObj.style.top); 

    x += 10;
    y += 10;  

    myObj.style.right = x + 'px';
    myObj.style.top = y + 'px';
    myObj.style.position = 'absolute';

    numcycles++;

    if (numcycles <= K_CYCLES)
    {
      setTimeout("flyer()",1000);
    }
  }

  function repeat()
  {
    flyer();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="infly()">

<div id="mydiv" style="width:50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;">
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="repeat()" value="fly"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Good work. But minor issue. Inside repeat function `numcycles` should be set to 0 so that the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Change your repeat function to look like this

```
function repeat() { setTimeout("fly()",5000) }
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want the function to constantly move without repeating the click you would need to call repeat(); at the end of fly() as well. (Of corse if that is, what you want to accomplish...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="javascript:repeat()">Fly</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="javascript:repeat()">Fly</a>
setTimeout("fly()",5000)
```